# Angular doesn't see that NoopAnimationsModule is included

Tags: angular

As in topic and in screenshots.
Angular throws error that I don't have `NoopAnimationsModule` included, but it is :/

`ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @routeSlide. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.`

[image]

I've tried to add it also to `app.module.ts` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` The same result.

EDIT:
It turned out that error massage wasn't precise. I had no `routeSlide` defined.

Comment: Stop `ng serve` and run again

Comment: And please post your error as code, not as picture.

Comment: Tried rerun `ng serve`

Comment: Angular documentation says that `NoopAnimationModule` is experimental as of today

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in your `app.module.ts`.

You have included the `NoopAnimationsModule` in your `RouterModule`'s imports.  However it is not visible to the `AppModule`.  You could fix this in one of two ways:

- Move the import into your `app.module` (preferred)
- Export the `NoopAnimationsModule` from your `RouterModule`

Comment: It also didn't worked. It turned out that error was wrong. I didn't have `routeSlide` animation defined.

Comment: It may have been both things?